# Is what I am doing valid for "killing" a summation?

Tags: summation

So I have this known property:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^nx^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}
$$

**EDIT:** Rewrote entire equation. I redid the formulation and the correct result I obtained is slightly different, but the same issue of simplifying the summation remains.

And I have my equation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
T(n) &= \sum_{i=0}^{\lg n} 4^i\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor c +  n^2 \\
&= c\sum_{i=0}^{\lg n}4^i \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor + n^2
\end{aligned}
$$

And I am trying to kill the summation.

** $\lg = \log_2$ FYI

Comment: When $\lg n$ is not an integer, then what is the definition of the sum?

Comment: $lg n - 1$ is not defined as an index in a summation. It needs to be a integer.

Comment: $n$ is always an integer, this has to do with $\Theta$-notation for solving recurrences. Such as solving merge-sort run-time.

Comment: What are the $[ ]$ ? I suspect something, because if it has no special meaning (like floor or ceil), then this is just summing $2^i$ and there should be no such fuss about it, provided that $\log_2(n)$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Let have $n=2^m$.

$S(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}4^i\lfloor \underbrace{2^{m-i}}_\text{integer}\rfloor c=c\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}2^{2i+m-i}=c\,2^m\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}2^i=2^m(2^m-1)c=n(n-1)c$

Comment: Or maybe you want it for any $n$ up to $\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor -1$ ? In that case you have to write $n=\sum d_j2^j$ in binary.